# my code will not execute the if/ elif part in this

Tags: python, if-statement, python-3.7

When I run this code (a portion of it) and I get to the word = input, it will run that and let me input my answer. But instead of doing the if / elif code, it will say exit code 0. I do not understand why this is happening so please help. I tried to remove code here and there but it changed nothing.

```
rand1 = random.randint(1, 2)
rand2 = random.randint(1, 4)
rand = random.randint(1, 1)
word = input("use a word that is 1-10 letters on a space, type a number 1 -    100 for the space: ")
if rand == "1":
    print("randomly generating")
elif rand1 == "1":
    a1 = word[0]
    a2 = word[1]
    a3 = word[2]
    a4 = word[3]
    a5 = word[4]
    a6 = word[5]
    a7 = word[6]
    a8 = word[7]
    a9 = word[8]
    a10 = word[9]
    letters()
```

this is just a portion as the entire code is too long to post in here

here is letters[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pm6XL.png)

Comment: Think about what the type of `rand` is, and what the type of `"1"` is. Are they the same?

Comment: `1 != "1"`, you're never going to make a string equal to an integer.

Comment: And didn't you probably want to process two _different_ cases in `if` and `elif`? Or if not: just delete the elif-line...

Comment: there is more after the elif that I did not show

Comment: but the elif you have shown will never run

Comment: can you please tell me how to use elif then? I am only starting to try and use it and only used if else before

Comment: see the code i have shown below

Comment: Looking at your screenshot of your parameters. Perhaps you would benefit from using ```*args``` instead of having 4 lines of parameters.

Comment: Joshua Nixon I have solved the problem. Thanks for trying to help though

Answer (score -1):

the reason is that rand generates a integer whereas you are comparing it with a string .

Also

```
if rand == "1":
    print("randomly generating")
elif rand1 == "1":
    a1 = word[0]
    a2 = word[1]
    a3 = word[2]
    a4 = word[3]
    a5 = word[4]
    a6 = word[5]
    a7 = word[6]
    a8 = word[7]
    a9 = word[8]
    a10 = word[9]
    letters()
```

this code seems illogical because both the if will always run as rand will always equal to 1 and elif will never run. its like saying to do something by not doing it :) rip english

Try using

```
if rand == "1":
    print("randomly generating")
    if rand1 == "1":
        a1 = word[0]
        a2 = word[1]
        a3 = word[2]
        a4 = word[3]
        a5 = word[4]
        a6 = word[5]
        a7 = word[6]
        a8 = word[7]
        a9 = word[8]
        a10 = word[9]
        letters()
```

Hope it helps